ду́хов versus духо́в
From this page and this page I understand that духо́в is the genitive of духи́, which means "perfume", and the translation of "spirit" is дух that has as a plural genitive ду́хов.
But in this poem by Fyodor Tyutchev we have this verse:

На мир таинственный духо́в,

and "perfume" does not seem to fit in the context while "spirits" seems to fit better. Is it the case that the stressing ду́хов is recent, otherwise how can we explain the stressing духо́в in this verse?


Is it the case that the stressing ду́xов is recent

It looks like that.
The first usage of the modern stress pattern (ду́ха / ду́хи / ду́хов, pattern 3a) in the poetic corpus seems to be from 1856:

Так было и со мной: я помню ясный взор,
Улыбку добрую, веселый разговор,
Что от меня вражду, сомненья и печали ―
Как ду́хов утра свет, внезапно отгоняли.
[А. Н. Плещеев. Листок из дневника : «Средь жизни будничной, ее тревог докучных...» (1856)]

The last usage of the old pattern (ду́ха / ду́хи / духо́в, pattern 3е, same as бог, волк) seems to be from 1902:

Страну видений и духо́в
Могучим пронизай законом.
[А. А. Блок. «Исчезла, отлетела в высь...» (11.07.1902)]

In between, you can see a gradual shift from the old pattern to the new one.
Note that in the nominative plural, the distinction between ду́хи "spirits" and духи́ "perfume" seems to have always been there.

In poetry either the stress would get shifted to fit the metre OR the old stress pattern was different from the modern one.

And which case is it here? I know examples of the second case, for instance : "За водой поу́тру шла" (Pushkin), but I could find that the unusual stressing existed (https://diffc_ru.academic.ru/6268/поутру), I don't know any example of the first case : do you have examples of classic poetry where the stressing is not respected just because it would not fit the metre?

@Bruno http://stihi.ru/2017/06/17/8636 I don't know how reliable the examples are in terms of accurate representation of the phenomenon and whether any research went into compiling the list. As far as поутру is concerned both stress patterns sound OK to me, albeit the one where the stress falls on the 2nd syllable being somewhat dated or less frequent. BTW 1st stressed syllable isn't jarring either.

Thank you, your link seems interesting but I don't understand its "status" (I think it weird that it begins with "5. Неправильные ударения", it seems that the beginning is missing and I was unable to find it). I don't really understand the sense of "неправильные": are they "mistakes" or is it a "weakness" due to the fact that the poet could not find another way to express what he wants to express, or is it intentional to produce some effect? How is it read? Respecting the metre or the right stress?
